# How to update value with help of userid in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a login page where I enter an username and password, then I get from server one userid which i store in my local database. It works but I have a problem in the second page updating the new value on the web server database. I want the value to change only when a user logs in. How can I pass a reference to a second page for a particular user and update the new value and make the change in the server database table. Your help is very vital to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get UserId save it in one Nsstring ..  create one more Nsstring in second class and create property for it.

```
@interface FaceBookProfile : UITableViewController {


    NSString *userId;

}
//getter setter method

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userId;
```

And pass the user id from first view to second view like this

```
FaceBookProfile *detailViewController = [[FaceBookProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBookProfile" bundle:nil];

    //to animate activity indicator


detailViewController.userId = userId;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

you can pass any value like above to any class